# How to get the size of an index created in a plpgsql block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to benchmark something. I want to create an index and get it's size in a plpgsql block.

This works:

```
haki=# create index ix on t(n);
CREATE INDEX

haki=# select pg_relation_size('ix');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
         22487040
```

When I try the same in a plpgsql block, I'm getting `ERROR: relation "ix" does not exist`:

```
haki=# DO $$DECLARE
haki$#     s int;
haki$# BEGIN
haki$#     PERFORM 'create index ix on t(n)';
haki$#     SELECT pg_relation_size('ix') INTO s;
haki$#     RAISE NOTICE 'size is %', s;
haki$# END$$;
ERROR:  relation "ix" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_relation_size('ix')
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that DDL is transactional and the block is not committed (I might also be wrong!). However, I am unable to find a way around that.

**Is it possible to get the size of an index created in a plpsql block?**

Comment: Have you tried without using PERFORM? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a350e80c80ba0e002d90b86a7faba711

Comment: Thanks MacNets, I haven't. How come it's working without perform?

Comment: If you like a traditional approach, here you are `begin; create index ix on t1(a); select pg_relation_size('ix');  rollback;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is to use `execute` and `rollback` then. I would suggest you to read it ["what are the difference between perform and execute on PL/pgSQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920998/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-execute)

```
DO 
$$
declare
  s int;
begin
  execute 'create index ix on t(n)';
  select pg_relation_size('ix') into s;
  raise notice 'size is %', s;
  select 1/0; -- This is for ROLLBACK
END 
$$;

NOTICE:  size is 8192
ERROR:  division by zero
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select 1/0"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement
```